# Manifolds with a finite but not trivial fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I came across this nice result:

> **Theorem:** If $M$ is a connected smooth manifold with finite fundamental group, then its first de Rham cohomology is trivial:
>   $$H^1_{dR}(M)=0.$$

However, I don't know any example of manifold with a finite but not trivial fundamental group. What are the nice examples of such manifolds?

Comment: There are closed manifolds with whatever finitely presented group you want as their fundamental group; in particular there are closed 4-manifolds with any chosen finite fundamental group. This is not true for 3-manifolds, where the list of possible finite fundamental groups is rather short.

Comment: Lens spaces are a $3$-manifold example.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the theorem follows directly from a very general result: $H^1_{dR}(M) \cong \hom_{\mathsf{Ab}}(\pi_1(M), \mathbb{R})$ (by the universal coefficient theorem and Hurewicz's theorem).

Answer (score 5):

Real projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for $n\geq 2$. This the quotient of the sphere $S^n$ by the antipodal action $x\sim -x$. In fact $S^n$ is a $2$-sheeted universal cover, which implies by covering space theory that its fundamental group is of order $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The special orthogonal group $SO(n)$ for $n\ge 3$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Small question about notation. When I was coming up through undergraduate algebra in Australia we would preferentially write $\mathbb Z_n$ over $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. While typically MSE users write the latter, longer form. Is there any important reason for this, or perhaps just a slightly different standard in the U.S.?

Comment: @SimonS $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is reserved for the $p$-adic integers.  Since people (unfortunately) do not usually meet $p$-adic numbers in their undergraduate degrees, instructors abbreviate $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for faster writing.

Comment: @guest: actually, it's more field dependent. Topologists often write $\mathbb Z_p$ whereas alegbraists use that notation for the $p$-adics.

Comment: I tend to write $\Bbb Z/n$, because it's perfectly clear which group/ring I mean, and I don't have to write that last $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

The Poincare homology sphere has fundamental group of order $120$, the [binary icosahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group). Any homology sphere must have a perfect fundamental group, but it need not be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In analogy to the answer of Robert Israel: The special linear group $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ (For a proof it is a smooth manifold see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640496/proof-that-the-special-linear-group-mathrmsln-mathbbr-is-a-smooth-mani).) has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n\geq 3$.

I am not totally sure, whether the projective orthogonal groups are smooth manifolds (somebody would need to verify that), but we have (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_orthogonal_group#Homotopy_groups).) for $n\geq 1$:
$$\pi_0\operatorname{PO}(2n)
\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$$
$$\pi_0\operatorname{PO}(2n+1)
\cong 1$$
$$\pi_1\operatorname{PO}(4n)
\cong\mathbb{Z}_2^2$$
$$\pi_1\operatorname{PO}(4n+2)
\cong\mathbb{Z}_4$$
$$\pi_1\operatorname{PO}(2n+1)
\cong\mathbb{Z}_2.$$