# Proof that the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

This is my definition of a smooth manifold I am supposed to work with:

Let $\mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The set $\mathcal{M}$ is a $k$-dimensional smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if:

$\mathcal{M}$ is given locally as the zero set of a function $F\colon W \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, where $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $F$ is of class $C^{\infty}$, and so that $\mathcal{M} \cap W = \{\, x \in W \mid F(x)=0\, \}$. My definition also requires that the Jacobian $\mathcal{J}_{F}(x)$ has rank $n-k$ for every point $x \in \mathcal{M} \cap W$.

$\ $

The special linear group is the set $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}) = \{\, A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid \det(A)=1\, \}$. I am trying to prove that this set is a smooth submanifold. From my reading online, I have understood that this submanifold has dimension $n^2-1$.

I'm going to make the identification $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\cong M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. My thoughts on proving this are to define a function $G\colon M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $G(A)=\det(A)-1$.

We have obviously $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}) = \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ where $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is open, and we know that $G$ is smooth since $\det$ is smooth. Furthermore, $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}) = \{\, A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid G(A)=0\, \}$.

Finally, the Jacobian of the function $\mathcal{J}_{G}$ is going to be a column vector of length $n^2$, and I will need to show that it has rank $1$. But since its a column vector, isn't this an immeadiate conclusion?

So to me it seems like this proof is finished. However, it seems a little too easy. Have I made any errors or omissions?

Comment: The Jacobian *might* be the zero vector (and so of rank 0) sometimes

Comment: I see, that's what is missing. Thanks! Wouldn't it suffice to show that just one of the components of the Jacobian is always non-zero? This will still be hard because derivatives of the determinant will not be clean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show that the Jacobian really is of rank $1$ (i.e., not equal to the zero vector), I suggest you expand $\det A$ by minors along the first column, say:
$$\det A =  \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}a_{i,1}M_{i,1}.$$
Of course, $(-1)^{i+1}M_{i,1}$ is in fact an entry of the Jacobian. So the Jacobian can only be zero, if also $\det A=0$. But we are looking at the Jacobian for points $A\in SL_n(\Bbb R)$!

Comment: This is so great. Expanding the determinant in the way you have done, $(-1)^{i+1}M_{i,1}$ will be a function of all the $a_{i,j}$ where $j \neq 1$ right? So if we differentiate $\det(A)$ with respect to $a_{i,1}$ for $1\leq i \leq n$, then we just have $(\mathcal{J}_{G})_{i}=(-1)^{i+1}M_{i,1}$? This is $n$ components of the Jacobian, and like you say if they are all zero then $\det(A)=0$, so at least some of these components are non-zero? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @Greg.Paul Yes, you are completely right. Except that the position in the Jacobian where $(-1)^{i+1}M_i$ occurs depends on how you enumerate the $n\times n$ matrix entry positions as the $n^2$ components of the Jacobian.